# Storing hierarchical (parent/child) data in Python/Django: MPTT alternative?

Tags: python, django, tree, mptt, django-mptt

I'm looking for a good way to store and use hierarchical (parent/child) data in Django. I've been using [django-mptt](http://code.google.com/p/django-mptt/), but it seems entirely incompatible with my brain - I end up with non-obvious bugs in non-obvious places, mostly when moving things around in the tree: I end up with inconsistent state, where a node and its parent will disagree on their relationship.

My needs are simple:

- Given a node:

  - find its root
  - find its ancestors
  - find its descendants
- With a tree:

  - easily move nodes (ie. change parent)

My trees will be smallish (at most 10k nodes over 20 levels, generally much much smaller, say 10 nodes with 1 or 2 levels).

I have to think there has to be an easier way to do trees in python/django. Are there other approaches that do a better job of maintaining consistency?

Comment: django-mptt is great - just read some of Daniel Roseman's answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324727/re-ordering-child-nodes-in-django-mptt/2326625#2326625) for some help with moving nodes around. Don't give up!

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the likely cause of my issues as well, but I don't trust myself to get that right every time - seems too easy to miss. I'll echo your comment: "Still a bit nervous about MPTT and the possibility of the tree getting into a bad state" :-) I take it you ended up happy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[django-treebeard](https://tabo.pe/projects/django-treebeard/) is another option. It has great documentation. I believe it meets all of your above requirements and includes some functions for checking the tree for problems and fixing those problems in the tree.

`Node.find_problems()` https://tabo.pe/projects/django-treebeard/docs/1.60/api.html#treebeard.models.Node.find_problems

`Node.fix_tree()` https://tabo.pe/projects/django-treebeard/docs/1.60/api.html#treebeard.models.Node.fix_tree

Comment: For what it's worth I ended up sticking with mptt and working through the issues, although I'm not particularly happy about it. treebeard looks like a good alternative so I'm accepting the answer.